# How get checkbox or checked property from WinTreeItem into WinTree (Coded UI)?

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I created Coded UI test which works with WinTree element.
I need to check 'checked' prorerty from some WinTreeItem.

'Checked' prorperty I can get from WinCheckBoxTreeItem, but I don't know how to get this checkbox.

Maybe do you know way to convert WinTreeItem to WinCheckboxTreeItem or get WinCheckbox from WinTreeItem.

You are only last hope!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Selected property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.wincontrols.wintreeitem.selected.aspx
in this case there is no IsChecked property however Selected works in the some way

Comment: Selected property return true, if it's selected, but not always checked.